# rtk query, transforming response to capitalize first letter of object keys not working

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit

I'm doing the following to capitalize all keys of an object response:

```
getBudget: build.query<BudgetType, void>({
    query: () => "budget",
    providesTags: ["Budget"],
    transformResponse: (response: BudgetType) => {
        const deepCopy = {...response};
        Object.keys(deepCopy).forEach((key) => key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1));
        console.log(deepCopy);
        return deepCopy;
    }
}),
```

Budget type:

```
export type BudgetType = {
    bills: number | null ,
    transportation: number | null ,
    health: number | null ,
    school: number | null ,
    food: number | null ,
    entertainment: number | null 
}
```

But it's not working, unsure why

Comment: `map()` returns an array of the results of the callback. You're not assigning that result anywhere. It doesn't modify the object in place.

Comment: I tried forEach as well, nothing changed.

Comment: That doesn't modify in place, either. You can't change strings in place, you need to create a new property: `deepCopy[key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = deepCopy[key]`